# метка, что метод/класс необходимо переделать

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Знаю, что при написания проекта некоторые методы/классы остаются без внимания, или написаны костылями, но что бы не забыть о них в дальнейшем их помечают. В гугле искал среди аннотаций или специальных комментариев именно эту функцию, но как вы поняли не нашел, может кто подскажет?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-todo.html

Comment: на такой случай можно ставить @Deprecated